# golang web scraper, ignoring specific cells of a table

Tags: go

I'm working on a small web scraper to just get a feel of golang. It currently is grabbing info off of a wiki from a table and then grabbing info specifically from cells. I don't currently have the code on me (not currently at home) but it looks fairly similar to this:

```
    func main() {
        doc, err := goquery.NewDocument("http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/MH4:_Item_List")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        doc.Find("tbody").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
                title := s.Find("td").Text()
                fmt.Printf(title)
        })
}
```

The issue is that on this website the first cell is an image, so it prints the image source which I don't want. How can I ignore the first cell in each row of the large table?

Comment: You can look for `td` with no child `a` anchor element.

Comment: Ok I can try and figure out how to do that. I just tried slicing the title to get the 4 first characters because they all start with "<img" and only displaying the title if it didn't start with "<img". Either this idea just doesn't work or I just simply don't know the syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's clear some things. A [`Selection`](http://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection) is a collection of nodes matching some criteria.

`doc.Find()` is [`Selection.Find()`](http://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Find) which returns a new `Selection` containing the elements matching the criteria. And [`Selection.Each()`](http://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Each) iterations over each of the elements of the collection and calls the function value passed to it.

So in your case `Find("tbody")` will find all `tbody` elements, `Each()` will iterate over all `tbody` elements and call your anonymous function.

Inside your anonymous function `s` is a `Selection` of one `tbody` element. You call `s.Find("td")` which will return a new `Selection` which will contain **all** the `td` elements of the current table. So when you call [`Text()`](http://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Text) on this, it will be the combined text contents of each `td` elements including their descendants. This is not what you want.

What you should do is call another `Each()` on the `Selection` returned by `s.Find("td")`. And check if the `Selection` passed to the 2nd anonymous function has an `img` child.

Example code:

```
doc.Find("tbody").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    // s here is a tbody element
    s.Find("td").Each(func(j int, s2 *goquery.Selection) {
        // s2 here is a td element
        if s3 := s2.Find("img"); s3 != nil && s3.Length() > 0 {
            return // This TD has at least one img child, skip it
        }
        fmt.Printf(s2.Text())
    })
})
```

Alternatively you could search `tr` elements and skip the first `td` child of each row by checking if the index passed to the 3rd anonymous function is `0` (first child), something like this:

```
doc.Find("tbody").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    // s here is a tbody element
    s.Find("tr").Each(func(j int, s2 *goquery.Selection) {
        // s2 here is a tr element
        s2.Find("td").Each(func(k int, s3 *goquery.Selection) {
            // s3 here is a td element
            if k == 0 {
                return // This is the first TD in the row
            }
            fmt.Printf(s3.Text())
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Oh ok I see thank you so much! these are both extremely helpful!

Comment: @icza How can this be modified to be able to handel empty `<tr>`? When I have  `<tr></tr><tr></tr>` I get this error: `panic: runtime error: index out of range`

Comment: @Kaah I don't see your code and I don't know where that panic occurs. Best would be to post that as a new question.